# Facebook Javascript SDK FB Undefined

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, undefined

When attempting to use the Facebook JS SDK, I keep running into the error `FB undefined`.
When I watch it through the JavaScript debugger on IE it runs through correctly during the page load, then at the end it is just undefined and no events that are subscribed to fire.
The goal: to make a page tab refresh the top most level page, to get past the fan gate.

Any ideas on what I am missing here?

Code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>

  window.fbAsyncInit = function(){

 FB.init({

 appId : 'APP CODE INSERTED HERE',

 status : true, // check login status

 cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session

 xfbml : true, // parse XFBML

 channelUrl : 'URL to Channel .ASPX'

 });


 // Additional initialization code here

     FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',

     function(response){

    top.location.href = 'Page to refreshed inserted here';
     });

 };

(function(d) 
{
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; 
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;

 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";

 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);

 }(document)
);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript to load the SDK Asynchronously doesn't match what the [Facebook SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) documentation currently shows.  See below:

```
// Load the SDK Asynchronously   
(function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

Both blocks of JavaScript to load the SDK are very similar.  Your JavaScript uses:

```
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
```

To load the SDK.  The most current version as documented by FB uses:

```
ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
```

Your version adds the source reference to load the FB JavaScript by appending to the HEAD HTML tag.  The most current version does this by finding the first SCRIPT reference and inserting the FB reference before that reference.

Perhaps your issue is caused by the subtle differences between these two methods.

One way to rule this out would be to temporarily hard code the loading of the FB JavaScript synchronously by placing the following HTML into your page's header:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_us/all.js"></script>
.
.
.
</head>
```